# HTML not running PHP in FireFox

Tags: php, html, firefox

I have a basic code in PHP (Test.php):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
echo ("Hello world!");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

It is called by an HTML file:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HTML/Adventures/mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <form action="Test.php">    
    <center><h1>LOGIN SCREEN</h1></center>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

1. When I run it directly through localhost, I get "Hello World"
2. When I run the HTML through IE browser, I get "Hello World"
3. But, when I run the HTML through FireFox, I get a blank screen.
   Can you please direct me to a setting that I can either embed into my code or into the Apache conf file that will correct this.  I don't want Firefox user to be excluded from my site..

Comment: Could you give us some context about which PHP server you're using?

Comment: I downloaded Xampp.  It is running PHP 7.4.7

Comment: You might find this interesting.  If I add <br> in between Hello and World, IE knows what to do.  Firefox starts spitting out the code after that command; even though it is within the " 's.

Answer (score 1):

If a script outputs in one browser and doesn't then it is definitely HTML or Browser side issue of non compatibility because script doesn't bothers which browser you are using. So just take PHP out of the equation here and focus on HTML and Browser.

Also check Test.php directly in Firefox. Because the previous page has nothing to do with this.

That way you remove different angles and close in onto the real issue.

Most probably it is browser issue.

Click on Inspect Element and check errors that browser outputs (if any)

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to be more specific.  "Inspect Element"?  I believe you are referring to Inspector Under Tools in Firefox.  I need direction.  I did run it and no errors were listed.

Comment: I think it is an HTML on Firefox issue.  I ran it as localhost on both browsers.  Both IE and FireFox came back with "Hello World!"  The only time it doesn't return anything is when the HTML in Firefox is used to run the PHP.

Comment: Why don't you rename your HTML file to .php

Comment: Well it did run that way.  I'm a little afraid to change my entire website to php just to make it run on Firefox.

Comment: If you do have an entire site behind this and not just some test project then I think you should go ahead and code the Hello World page into full fledged HTML page. Also run that through W3C validator. Try updating your Firefox version (if it isn't updated)

Comment: One very last thing that could fix this is rename Test.php to test.php use smaller case for file name. I have experienced similar issues back in 2004 or so but I just remembered it.

Comment: Oh my ..... that works.  It was the capitalization.  Thank you so much for the help.